# How do I deal with a floor function is a system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How would one solve an equation with a floor function in it:
\begin{cases}
  y=12(x-\lfloor x \rfloor) \\ 
  x=12(y-\lfloor y \rfloor) 
\end{cases}
Maybe an algebraic method could be used?

Answer (score 2):

Write $x = m + \alpha, y = n + \beta$ where $m, n$ are integers and $0 \leq \alpha, \beta < 1$. The system is equivalent to the conditions $x = 12 \beta$, $y = 12 \alpha$ and the linear system
$$\begin{align*}
-\alpha + 12\beta &= m, \\
12 \alpha - \beta &= n.
\end{align*}
$$
Solving this system, we find 
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{143}(m + 12n) ,\quad \beta = \frac{1}{143}(12m + n).$$
Therefore the solutions to the original system are all pairs $(x,y)$ with
$$x = \frac{12}{143}(m + 12n) ,\quad y = \frac{12}{143}(12m + n),$$
where $m, n$ are integers satisfying $0 \leq 12m + n, m + 12n < 143$. Moreover it is clear from the original problem that we must have $0 \leq m, n \leq 11$, and that all $m, n$ satisfying these inequalities yield solutions, except $m = n = 11$. Since $m + 12n$ runs through all numbers $0, 1, 2, \dots , 142$, we find in conclusion that the solutions are all pairs $(x,y)$ with
$$x = 12p/143, \text{ for $p = 0, 1, 2, \dots , 142$ }; \quad y = 12(x - \lfloor x \rfloor).$$

Comment: Your answer is more complete than mine. Nice finish.

Comment: Thanks very much for the very neat and clear solution but would be glad if you can explain how you get " 0≤12m+n,m+12n<143".

Comment: That's because the condition on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is that they belong to $[0,1)$.

Comment: Can you show me how to break the  given two equations into 23 set of simple of linear equations from which the 143 points can be found geometrically? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure. For a fixed value of $m$, all the solutions lie on one line. The solutions will be located on the $12$ lines corresponding to $m = 0, 1, 2, \dots, 11$. Perhaps you want to take the intersections with the $12$ lines given by $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots, 11$.

Comment: rewriting the two equations as y=12(x−a ),x=12(y-b) and putting integers from 0 to 11 for a and b will give me 24 linear equations and using graphical calculator I can see all the 144-1 solutions. But I wonder  I cannot find  mathematically reasoning behind it which allows me to replace the floor function value for integer values from 0 to 11 plus do not know why there is an extra one value ( 144 instead of 143)

Comment: $0 \leq y - \lfloor y \rfloor < 1$, so multiplying by $12$, we find $0 \leq x < 12$. Therefore $a = \lfloor x \rfloor \in \{0, 1, \dots, 11\}$. Similarly for $b$. If you read my answer, you'll see that $a = b = 11$ is an exception. Just a comment now. If you already have a specific solution you want to understand but don't understand all the details, it's best to put that information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$x = n+a$,
$y=m+b$
where
$0 \le a, b < 1$.

Then
$m+b
=12a
$,
so
$0 \le m+b < 12$.

Similarly
$n+a
= 12b
$
so
$0 \le n+a < 12$.

This gives a very finite
number of possible cases,
which can be readily checked.

Possibly more could come from
$n+a
= 12 b
= 12 (12a-m)
=144a-12m
$
or
$n+12m
=143a
$.